# AbstractController::ActionNotFound para a destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, route, controles

Olá,

Tenho duas aplicações rodando no Heroku com o mesmo código, só que estou tendo um probleminha na versão de **produção**.

Ao tentar fazer uma requisição, tenho o seguinte log:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'destroy' could not be found for Managers::RecruitmentsController)
```

O problema é que ele está tentando buscar no controller `Managers::RecruitmentsController`, mas o correto seria em `Managers::ApplicantsController`, como já acontece na versão **dev**:

```
Started DELETE "/managers/recruitments/1/applicants/7" for 179.156.49.112 at
Processing by Managers::ApplicantsController#destroy as HTML
```

Bem, essta solicitação vem do *link_to* abaixo:

```
 <%= link_to "Outra chance?", "javascript:;", id: "newChance", method: 'delete', btn: true, style: :link, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#modalNewChance', 'data-applicant-id' => applicant.id %>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script language="javascript">
   $("#newChance").on('click', function() {
       $("#linkNewChance").attr('href', '/managers/recruitments/<%=  @recruitment.id %>/applicants/' + $("#newChance").data('applicant-id'));
       });
 </script>
```

Meu controller:

```
class Managers::ApplicantsController < Managers::BaseController
...
def destroy
  @applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])

  CandidatesMailer.new_chance(@applicant).deliver
  CompanyMailer.new_chance_company(@applicant).deliver

  @applicant.destroy

  flash[:success] = "Aplicação resetada com sucesso. Candidato tem nova chance."
  redirect_to managers_recruitment_path(params[:recruitment_id])
end
```

Minhas rotas:

```
namespace :managers do
 get "guide/index"
 resource :dashboard, only: :show
 resource :profile,   only: [:show, :edit, :update]
 resource :company,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
   resource :payment, only: [:edit, :update]
 end
 resources :plans,    only: [:new, :create], path_names: { new: 'choose' }
 resources :recruitments do
  member do
    patch 'close'
  end
  resources :applicants do
    member do
      put 'comment'
      patch 'comment'
    end
  end
 end
end
```

[Aqui estão as Rotas relacionadas aos controllers citados.](https://gist.github.com/augustoppimenta/afe3cbcb6163f2e9cf13)

Comment: o que aparece quando você roda uma rake routes?

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz,aparece todas as rotas, mas quanto ao controller em questão vou editar em minha resposta.

Comment: Você verificou se a rota está certa no html?

Comment: Poxa @ThiagoDiniz...Não pensei nisso! Eu refatorei o código, transferindo o `link_to` para uma view respondesse ao mesmo controller que no caso era o Applicants. Tipo, a view que eu estava fazendo a requisição era relacionada ao controller Recruitments, então eu transferir o código para a view que responde ao controller Applicants, sem perder valor para o negócio. Não sei se esse era o problema mas acabou funcionando. PS.: Sou iniciante no mundo Rails!

Answer (score 1):

o end-point que é chamado no trecho de código

```
<script language="javascript">
  $("#newChance").on('click', function() {
  $("#linkNewChance").attr('href', '/managers/recruitments/<%=  @recruitment.id %>/applicants/' + $("#newChance").data('applicant-id'));
  });
 </script>
```

Leva para o controller `Managers::RecruitmentsController` mesmo... o Rails tá fazendo certo, como pode ser observado na linha 26 da saída das rotas que você postou

https://gist.github.com/augustoppimenta/afe3cbcb6163f2e9cf13#file-routes-L26

não há nenhum redirect ocorrendo antes do router do Rails processar sua URL?